# Bug on C++11 regex while running on Ubuntu 14.04 (g++ / clang) but not in Windows (mingW)

Tags: regex, linux, c++11, ubuntu-14.04

I need to parse a file using C++11 regex (not Boost, not external libraries, not calling bash or python routines, and so forth).

First of all, I need to discard the lines which do not contain any URL domain.

Then, from those kept lines, I need to extract the domains and return them in a container.

Example: from https://www.xjr.com/my_folder/index.html, I need to preserve only: www.xjr.com.

So, I built up my own following regex:

```
std::regex urlRgx("((([[:print:]])?)*(https|http)://(www|ww2|web))\\.
([[:alnum:]]{2,256}.[[:alpha:]]{2,4})((/([[:alnum:]])?)*(([[:print:]])?)*)");
```

Because of different reasons (and headaches with regex incompatibilities), I finished compiling and running my program, without issues, in CodeBlocks 16.01, under Windows 10 (using MinGW: g++-6.*).

BUT, when I came to my desired environment, Ubuntu 14.04, the program compiled successfully but, while running, it simply gets stuck, and provides no output.

Always in Ubuntu 14.04, I tried:

1. Compiling on CodeBlocks 16.01, with g++-6.* and clang 3.8. Result: no output.
2. Compiling from command line, with same compilers. Result: no output.

Note: I run the program, but it never ends; it just remains stuck, with the blinking cursor...

Of course, I commented the regex, and tried other outputs and arrived to identify that the issue is in the regex itself.

I wonder if there is some "automatic" conversion done by minGW, in Windows, which is hiding some error in the regex. And then, in POSIX, it is simply not working.

Could you please provide any useful advice?

Comment: What are the parts with `((...)?)*`? It seems to me that they can match an empty string in infinitely many ways, that wouldn't sound very sane. I think the regex is pathological for some reason and this would be my first suspect.

Comment: First and third parts: (([[:print:]])?)* : It looks for any printable character, which can be present or not (?) and any amount of them (*). Consider, please, that the domain might be present (or not) in whichever part of the string.
Second part: looks for alphanumeric chars, like: "/my_folder/index.html".
So, no empty strings.

Comment: "Present in any amount or not" is what the asterisk alone does. No need for the ?.

Comment: Question mark: "present or not"; Asterisk: "any amount of the previous". So: if something is present ("?") (printable, etc.), it can be present in any amount ("*"). If it is not present, then is "any amount of nothing".
Example 1: _flasjfña jffjñsa !eqson234%%%_ **mydoimain.org** _fahfñal )(/$""kk_ : In this case, since garbage is present before and after _mydomain.org_ , I need to discard that garbage and keep only _mydomain.org_ (and discard also subdomains, folders, etc.).
Example 2: _urpoeurpqpruqwerupurepq urpouqrpoqurepq r_  In this case, I need to reject all the line: no domain there.

Comment: You're missing that "any amount" includes "zero amount". So `[[:print:]]*` does all that you're expecting from `(([[:print:]])?)*`: it matches any nonempty sequence of printable characters as well as the empty string. Give it a try.